# Save entire contents of a web page without a browser

Tags: .net, vb.net, html

I've been using the code below to download web pages without a browser. The problem is that it doesn't save all of the code like Firefox when you save a page as complete. Internet Explorer doesn't save all of the code either nor does a web client. I've used Gecko and XULRunner but I get errors all the time and it adds like 20-40 MB to your project. Firefox saves a web page complete around 55KB. Internet Explorer (app and web control) save a complete page at 24KB. A lot of code is left out from the source code. With the code below, is their anyway to save the entire contents of a web page? Maybe through Headers?

```
    Try
        Dim wrWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://websta.me/p/799354489959753224_22167696"), HttpWebRequest)
        wrWebRequest.Timeout = 30000
        wrWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0"
        Dim wrWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(wrWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim strStream As Stream = wrWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim bytBuffer(65536) As Byte
        Dim intBytesToRead As Integer = CInt(bytBuffer.Length)
        Dim intBytesRead As Integer = 0
        While intBytesToRead > 0
            Dim intNumber As Integer = strStream.Read(bytBuffer, intBytesRead, intBytesToRead)
            If intNumber = 0 Then
                Exit While
            End If
            intBytesRead += intNumber
            intBytesToRead -= intNumber
        End While
        strStream.Close()

        Dim fsFileStream As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Data.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        fsFileStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
        fsFileStream.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: What do you mean by "entire content"? Do you mean all css files, scripts, images etc. anything needed to make it work offline in addition to HTML?

Comment: If that's the case, it's tough stuff. What if some image is loaded asynchronously upon user input? How can you know beforehand that another resource won't be loaded?

Comment: checkout http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2174

Comment: Thanks for your responses. What I really need is the complete html code. For some reason Firefox saves it all but other browsers don't. I'm kind of screwed at this point because I needed a web control to parse 65+ pages of code quickly.

Comment: asb, thanks for the link. I'm checking it out now. It could be what I was looking for.